# NodeJS and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have just installed these nodejs and socket.io but I am having problems with getting the client to connect to the server.

In my server I have:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');

var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.emit('Hi.') ;

});
```

And on my client:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('connect', function () {
  socket.emit('set nickname', confirm('What is your nickname?'));
  socket.on('ready', function () {
    console.log('Connected !');
    socket.emit('msg', confirm('What is your message?'));
  });
});
```

I am getting a number of errors in Chrome inspector:

```
GET http://localhost:9261/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not serving the client via nodeJS, this will not work :

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

try using the this instead:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried that, I don't get the 404 anymore, just get require and io not defined.

Comment: are you sure you have installed socket.io ? you must open a terminal, go to the same directory as your server and then write 'npm install socket.io'

Comment: im using windows, I used command prompt to install it in my current app folder (im using dreamweaver), it installed socket.io into a folder called node_modules, so the directory is like this: F:\xampp\htdocs\mySite\node_modules\socket.io

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're sending only the 'Hello World' to the client, not the html with the client code.

Your server code should look like this (from http://socket.io/#how-to-use ):

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Your client code should be in `index.html`. Also make sure that you have a folder named `socket.io` that contains the script `socket.io.js`

Comment: I have gone through it a couple of times but I still can't seem to get it working. I now have the errors: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined

Comment: "require is not defined" - seems like you're using require on the client side (which is wrong). How are you running the server?

Comment: From command prompt using the command: node server.js, it runs fine with no errors.

Comment: By the way I'm running the server on the same machine as I am trying to run the client, is this not possible? Must be on a different machine/VM?

Comment: The code above is now giving me an error when I try to run the server: Cannot find module 'socket.io'

Comment: Did you install it via `npm` ?

Comment: I reinstalled it and that fixed that error, but I'm still getting io is not defined on the client part.

Answer (score 1):

It is not able to connect because your client is not able to find socket.io.js
you can resolve by using proper file, from node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\dist directory use socket.io.js and put it into your local directory and use it in script tag.

Answer (score 1):

> `<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");`

for this way client connected to node server.This will work

Answer (score 0):

Also note that when you move to production the code in your client should be updated:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

To something like

```
var socket = io.connect('my_host');
```

I've sent the `my_host` to the client side script with the page where I'm loading `socket.io`, by extracting the parameters `req.headers.host`, so for me it looks like:

```
 io.connect('http://' + host)
```

You can expose variables on the client side through `express-expose`.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because `io` was not properly instantiated, thus **Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined**

```
// Instantiate without argument
var io = require('socket.io')();
// Instantiate with new keyword
var Server = require('socket.io')
  , io = new Server();

// Instantiate io server with app as argument
var app = require('http').createServer(handlerFunc)
  , io = require('socket.io')(app);
app.listen(80);

// Attaching socket.io with express server
var app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(80, handlerFunc);
```